# How to do hyper-parameter tuning using spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I'm building a Logistic regression model using spark ml. I have manually split my data into training, validation and testing sets. I'd like to use `ParamGridBuilder` and do some parameter tuning but using the validation data I have. Both `TrainValidationSplit` and `CrossValidator` randomly split the data for validation, thought it is not useful for me as I have a manually created validation set. How can I use my own validation set to do parameter tuning? Can I still use `ParamGridBuilder`?